# How to get UIDocumentMenuViewController functionality in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, ios11

In iOS 11 `UIDocumentMenuViewController` is marked as deprecated.

It is recommended to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, which existed before and has only a subset of `UIDocumentMenuViewController` functionality (in previous versions it was invoked by `UIDocumentMenuViewController`).

I can't see that something new was added to it so that it can augment removal of `UIDocumentMenuViewController`.

Somehow I doubt that iOS 11 removed such an important feature without offering some new way to do it, but I can't see it right now, so does anyone know something regarding this?

Comment: So what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @phil primary goal would be to allow users to pick something from e.g. Dropbox if they have their app installed, the secondary goal would be to add my own entries to that menu where different providers are presented.

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I can't help you but I'm wondering if Apple plans to move all this functionality to the new Files app (introduced in iOS 11). Good luck with your task!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 10 and previous the `UIDocumentMenuViewController` opens with Dropbox, Google Drive... then is necessary a `Menu` to you can add items dinamically as you need.
In iOS 11 only one item `Explore...` is presented in Menu, then now, you can use a ActionSheet with your custom items and the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.